# how to properly use teodorpatras/SideMenuController?

Tags: swift

Recently I am looking for a Navigation Drawer like on Android, then i found this `https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController`

I already installed it on my project using Carthage, and do everything about installation. But when i tried to use it, I don't really get the instruction.

[image]

I already added the bar button into my navigation bar, but I don't know where to put the code/class needed

```
class CustomSideMenuController: SideMenuController {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    SideMenuController.preferences.drawing.menuButtonImage = UIImage(named: "menu")
    SideMenuController.preferences.drawing.sidePanelPosition = .overCenterPanelLeft
    SideMenuController.preferences.drawing.sidePanelWidth = 300
    SideMenuController.preferences.drawing.centerPanelShadow = true
    SideMenuController.preferences.animating.statusBarBehaviour = .showUnderlay
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

}

There is an example folder in the github, but I simply can't build, too many error shown :/ So does anyone have an example project using this library? or tell me how to use it :|

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a CustomSideMenuController which will be your base controller from where all the controller will be routed and paste the above code inside that viewController class

and create segue with class `CenterContainmentSegue` from the CustomSideMenuController to whatever controller you want as landing view

you have to create a tableViewcontroller for the side menu and make a segue to the CustomSideMenuController with class `SideContainmentSegue`

dont forgot to add the `performSegueWithIdentifier("", sender: nil)` to the viewdidload of this CustomSideMenuController

For the errors, this is not available in swift 3. So Please specify your xcode version that u use for development